# Viewhelper f:link.typolink in TYPO3 9.5 LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

The viewhelper

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">
```

works only with strings like '19 _blank - "testtitle with whitespace"'

But since 8.7 LTS typolinks are formatted like "t3://page?uid=4284". This works:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="4284">
```

this dont:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="t3://page?uid=4284">
```

but the typolink widgets works the new way - there is no possiblity anymore to get the old syntax.

Any ideas how to deal with a modern typolink in a viewhelper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested  `<f:link.typolink parameter="t3://page?uid=23">test</f:link.typolink>` on TYPO3 9.5.3. It works for me, as long the uid refers to a valid page. When the uid is not valid, only the text is renderd without any link.

The new format is also documented as an example in
[TyposcriptReference: Typolink](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Typolink.html#parameter).

It should work.

**Valid uid:**

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="t3://page?uid=23">test</f:link.typolink>
```

Result:

```
<a href="/test.html">test </a>
```

**Wrong uid:**

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="t3://page?uid=9999999">test</f:link.typolink>
```

Result:

```
test
```

**Alternative with `<f:format.html>`:**

```
<f:format.html><a href="t3://page?uid=23">my link</a></f:format.html>
```

Result:

```
<a href="/test.html">my link</a>
```

Comment: Jesus. You are right, the page was not accessable for all users ... shame on me. I do know that typolink only works when the page is accessable, but i was totally convinced that the page was acessable. Only it was not ... Well, many thanks, and sorry for the noise.

Comment: @lisardo another trick is to check the source of the test files for a VH. I often get a real impression what is possible with a specific VH and (much important) what values are already tested within the TYPO3 core.